# How can I stop users from viewing folders that have no index page but other pages on my web site using PHP or mod rewrite?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I just wanted to know how to stop user from viewing folders without index pages using PHP or mod rewrite?

**All of these answers are good but I will rate the one with the most votes.**

Comment: You surely mean "viewing -->folders<-- without index pages"?

Comment: thats what I meant sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Configure](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/configuring.html) your web server to *not* automatically serve directory indexes.

Using Apache, this is done with the [`-Indexes` option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options):

```
<Directory /web/docs/spec>
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

You can also put this `Options -Indexes` directive in an `.htaccess` file in the specific directory.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need PHP for this. Just put a blank `index.html` in the directory.

Answer (score 3):

By viewing folders, I assume there is a directory listing that you don't want visible. In that case, in your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This can be done on a per-directory basis. See:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory